# Blank Output C++

Tags: c++, output

I did my coding just now but the output was blank. I cannot cin input because of this. What is my mistake here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ( )
{
    int leg1, leg2;
    double hypotenuse;
    ofstream outfile("C:\\Users\\Irwin Chrisman\\Desktop\\HYPLENG.txt");

    outfile <<"Hypotenuse length of three triangles"<<endl<<endl;
    outfile <<"Triangle number\tLeg 1 length\tLeg 2 length\tHypotenus Length"<<endl;
    cin>>leg1;
    cin>>leg2;
    hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(leg1, 2)+pow(leg2, 2));
    outfile <<"1\t\t"<<leg1<<"\t\t"<<leg2<<"\t\t"<<hypotenuse<<endl;
    cin>>leg1;
    cin>>leg2;
    hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(leg1, 2)+pow(leg2, 2));
    outfile <<"2\t\t"<<leg1<<"\t\t"<<leg2<<"\t\t"<<hypotenuse<<endl;
    cin>>leg1;
    cin>>leg2;
    hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(leg1, 2)+pow(leg2, 2));
    outfile <<"3\t\t"<<leg1<<"\t\t"<<leg2<<"\t\t"<<hypotenuse<<endl;
    outfile.close( );
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing output to a file? I think you want to write output to `stdout` using `std::cout`.

Comment: @kiner_shah as an intro, I am very new to C++ and I've never learnt any other programming language before. I need the output to key in the values of leg 1 and leg 2 of the triangle but there was no output.

Comment: The program does not write anything to standard output.   So, as far as the user is concerned, it outputs nothing to screen/console and immediately waits for input.   If the file `C:\Users\Irwin Chrisman\Desktop\HYPLENG.txt`  is successfully created, all output from your program is written to that, so you won't see it unless you open that file (e.g. in a file viewer).  If creation of the file fails then, obviously, no output is produced. Nothing prevents the program receiving input, except your reluctance to provide input if no output to screen is visible (which is beyond control of your code)

Comment: @Peter Thanks I think I understand now. I just need to key in the input from keyboard even tho the output is blank right? I opened the .txt file and I found out it worked just now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're writing output to a file, if you want to see the output in the console, consider using the `std::cout` and include the header `#include <iostream>`. [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/9sYRMfRzbo) is an example!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ( )
{
    int leg1, leg2;
    double hypotenuse;

    cout <<"Hypotenuse length of three triangles"<<endl<<endl;
    cout <<"Triangle number\tLeg 1 length\tLeg 2 length\tHypotenus Length"<<endl;
    cin>>leg1;
    cin>>leg2;
    hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(leg1, 2)+pow(leg2, 2));
    cout <<"1\t\t"<<leg1<<"\t\t"<<leg2<<"\t\t"<<hypotenuse<<endl;
    cin>>leg1;
    cin>>leg2;
    hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(leg1, 2)+pow(leg2, 2));
    cout <<"2\t\t"<<leg1<<"\t\t"<<leg2<<"\t\t"<<hypotenuse<<endl;
    cin>>leg1;
    cin>>leg2;
    hypotenuse = sqrt(pow(leg1, 2)+pow(leg2, 2));
    cout <<"3\t\t"<<leg1<<"\t\t"<<leg2<<"\t\t"<<hypotenuse<<endl;
}
```